# How to have python create log entries when called by postfix

Tags: python, logging, postfix-mta

I have configured postfix with `mailbox_command = /path/to/my_python_script.py`.

If my python script fails, I see the results of the exception in /var/log/mail.log.

When I try to create a logging.error(message), that message does not appear in the mail.log file.

Is there a way to make that happen without just raising a SystemExit exception?

Comment: Can you show how you configure logging in your script? What version of Python runs the script?

Comment: @VinaySajip
I stripped that code out, but I believe I was just doing ... `import logging ...  logging.error('This is an error message')`

Comment: It's python 3.10.12